# Data transfer modifier error

Tags: modifiers

I have a sphere curved surface, and I have moved some faces which caused a shading issue. So I tried to do a data transfer, but its not working. And I'm also getting an error: Source and destination cannot be used in this case. What am I doing incorrect?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If your DT 'Mapping' is via  'Topology' , the source and destination must have corresponding geometric elements. Have you edited the geometry?

Comment: Hi Robin. Sorry but I cannot understand when you referred to the DT mapping.

Comment: Hi bb! I was just using  DT as an abbreviation for Data Transfer.  :) See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *Data Transfer* modifier is attempting to use 'Topology' as the means of mapping data from one object to another. Your objects do not have the same topology, so this wont work; Blender can't find a vertex on the source object corresponding to every vertex on the target object.

Instead, you could change the vertex-group which the modifier affects as follows:

[image]

(These are the vertices the modifier will *not* affect)

Then change the mapping of the transfer from 'Topology' to something more appropriate...

[image]

Here, because the source is spherical, 'Projected Face Interpolated' seems to work well.

Note the double-arrow to the right of the Vertex Group field is checked, to select the *inverse* of the 'TG' group.